# new to android - understanding java syntax

Tags: java, android

I am going through the following vogella tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#expandablelistview_example

I found this code which I dont understand "private final SparseArray groups"

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private final SparseArray<Group> groups;
```

I tried to study the java topic: generics but that didnt help

Comment: i did find that SparseArray belongs to some group called: import android.util.SparseArray;  but that is all i understand

Comment: http://www.learnjavaonline.org/

Comment: Sparse arrays and expandable lists are fairly obscure topics.

Comment: At least you do some effort before posting a question (compared to other users who pretend to be a developer by simply posting a question with "please give me the code!"): learn Java first then focus on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

private: the field is only visible within the class
final: once the field has been set to a value, it cannot be changed anymore (sure you can add elements to the collection, but you cannot assign a new SparseArray to the field groups)

Some information on SparseArray: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html

> SparseArrays map integers to Objects. Unlike a normal array of Objects, there can be gaps in the indices. It is intended to be more efficient than using a HashMap to map Integers to Objects.

Comment: the part which i dont understand is the <Group>groups

Answer (score 0):

for SparseArray please see .http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html

it is just a map.it maps integers to object. simply like list but in SparseArray  there may be gap in indexes.

```
private final SparseArray<Group> groups;

private : access modifier (not accessible to outside of class members)
final : can't be reassigned.
<Group>  : SparseArray will contains Group type of elements
```

for other question keep commenting.

Comment: the part which i dont understand is the <Group>groups